# CSS: How to force proportional image scaling beyond 1:1px

Tags: css, image, scaling

**The Question:** Using CSS, how can I make arbitrary images scale up/down proportionally to fill the available space determined by the boundaries of a max-height/max-width environment in a browser frame EVEN if the frame is way larger than the image? The following works for images bigger than the frame, but small images will NOT SCALE UP beyond 1:1 screen:image pixels.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="frame"><span class="helperSpanToAlignImageVertically"></span>
    <img class="imageRaw" src="somesmallimg.jpg">
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.frame {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.helperSpanToAlignImageVertically {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.imageRaw {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

**An Example:** Say the browser window is 1000 x 1000 px.

1)
Say the raw image size is 200 x 100 px. The visual result should be an image of 900 x 450 px, centered inside the browser window.

2)
Say the raw image size is 1000 x 2000 px. The visual result should be an image of 450 x 900 px, centered inside the browser window.

Note: I want this all to be fluid. If the browser window size changes, the image should always scale proportionally.

Comment: scaling up an image will be ugly for small images like that, but for it to scale up you also need width or height to be 90% as well.

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for the object-fit property:  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-object-fit-object-position/

Comment: Ugliness is acceptable. Yes, but setting width/height to a fixed 90% will result in unproportional image distortion, which is not what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scale image to fit a bounding box - CSS-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994493/scale-image-to-fit-a-bounding-box-css-only)

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for sharing the link. I didn't know about this. Probably because browsers don't support it yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit