# Image in Shiny via CSS

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to add an image to my Shiny application (set up with shiny dashboard) that resides in a `box` and automatically resizes with the box.

I thought this could be done with some HTML/CSS tricks and found [Scale image to fit a bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994493/scale-image-to-fit-a-bounding-box/). Thus, I created a `custom.css` in a `www` folder in my app and added the following CSS

```
.someimage {
  background-image: url('someimage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.main-header .logo {
  font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

with `someimage.png` residing in the same place. The application looks like

`ui.R`

```
# UI
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Title"), 
  dashboardSidebar(), 
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
    ),
    box(title = "Some image",
        tags$div(class = 'someimage')
    )
  ))
```

`server.R`

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

As a test I also altered the header font, which does get changed into serif. Furthermore, when I open the developer tools in Chrome and look for I find the correct `div` and css class.

I also found this [Embedding Image in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app) but it didn't really help

Comment: Are you able to just call the image in an HTML() wrapper? So instead of placing your image in the CSS markup, actually load it in HTML. Something like HTML("<img src='source-path' class='img-responsive' />"). Bootstrap (which is the CSS framework that shiny is built with) has a class called img-responsive that may help. See here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: that works beautifully!