# <img> vs. background-image: url('') in fixed header (explanation)

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

Why do some websites use the `background-image: url('')` CSS rule for their logo that is in the fixed header instead of the `<img>` tag?

I was going through the code for the music websites: Shazam and Deezer and realized something that amazed me but that also worried me...

Example 1: (This is the code from Shazam's website)

```
<a class="header-logo" href="https://www.shazam.com/" data-shz-beacon="providerdesc=home-logo" style="background-image: url(&quot;/resources/a935eea48a74b098f4b697dccd8c5322e30f48cc/logos/logo.png&quot;);"></a>
```

^In this case, they added an `<a>` tag and then added an inline-style with the `background-image: url(''`) CSS rule, instead of adding an `<img>` tag.

Example 2: (This is the code from Deezer's website)

*HTML*

```
<h1>
<span class="index-header-logo logo logo-deezer-hp"></span>
<span class="sr-only" lang="en">Deezer</span>
</h1>
```

*CSS*

```
.logo-deezer-hp {
background-image: url(/cache/images/common/logos/deezer_hp.51c8087603572ee440e73719f69ff50d.png);
height: 40px;
width: 185px;}
```

^In this case they added a `<span>` tag inside a `<h1>` tag, gave a class to the first span tag and then through CSS they added the `background-image: url('')` CSS rule.

---

So i asked myself:

1- Why did Shazam and Deezer not use the `<img>` tag to add their logo?
2- Why did Shazam not use the `<img>` tag inside the `<a>` tag?
3- Why did Deezer use the `<h1>` and `<span>` tag to add their logo?

I researched a lot about this but still can't understand why they did not use the `<img>` tag for their logo...

**My question is...**

"I use the `<img>` tag to put my logo inside the fixed header for my website, why did Shazam and Deezer not use that tag? How/Why did they decide to use the `background-image: url('')` CSS rule instead?

Every other website uses the `<img>` tag, why did they not?!?!

I really need to know why both of these websites decided that it was better to use `background-image: url('')` ...

Comment: Because it's more responsive, look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10016640/5323912

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image

Comment: i read the link but still can't get a proper answer @ashishsingh

Comment: @N1gthm4r3 it's more responsive in which way? I mean, wouldn't the `<img>` tag accomplish the same thing??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in the shazams's website, they used  tag to give their logo a link that when you clicked the logo it will redirect you to their home page, some websites uses a logo and a separate Home button for their site for me I can see that they used  tag that serves as a button and instead of text, they used an image or simply their logo for a much effective user experience.

About Deezer, they used  tags to have both, I say when creating / designing your own website its all about creativity, and you're all free to use every element of HTML has to offer.

Conclusion, for me I use  tag for a much responsive image / logo display (especially in working bootstrap components), while having it in the "background-image", it will be much easier to implement it to other elements you have in your website, let's say you'll be putting it in a class and just give it to an element whenever you want to display the image you've used.

Comment: but isn't it incorrect to use a  `<h1>` tag for something else than a header?