# How do I fit an image inside a div without it resizing the parent element, but also being responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

This is the HTML I have:

```
<div class="data">
<div class="dataispod">
<div class = "detaljilevo">
    <div class="detaljilevosub">
        <h1 class="naslovdetalji"><?=$podaci->naziv?></h1>

        <h4 class="kategorijadetalji"><span><?=$podaci->nazivKategorije?> zadatak • Neizvršen</span></h4>

        <h4 class="opisdetalji"><?=$podaci->opis?></h4>

        <h5 class="datum">Datum kreiranja: <?=$noviDatumKreiranja?></h5>
    </div>

    <div id="buttonwrapperdetalji">
        <button type="submit" class="dugmedetalji" name="button" onclick="izvrsiZadatak();"><span class="puntekst">Izvrši zadatak</span><span class="krataktekst">Izvrši</span></button>
        <form action="izmeni.php">
        <button type="submit" class="dugmedetalji" name="button2" onclick="izmeni();"><span class="puntekst">Izmeni zadatak</span><span class="krataktekst">Izmeni</span></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slikacontainer">
    <div class="slikawrap">
        <img src="../slike/<?=$podaci->slika?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I have:

```
.data {
    margin: 80px 60px 0px 80px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #BEBDC3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 400px;
    width: 70%;
}

.dataispod {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

.detaljilevo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
}

.detaljilevosub {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.slikacontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.slikawrap {
    height: 60%;
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #555555;
}

.slikawrap img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The user is supposed to upload the picture and I'm supposed to display it in the element. The user is allowed to upload pictures of any dimensions, so I'm trying to figure out a way to display them.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours but nothing seems to be working. I put the width as percentage on the `slikawrap` class so it would be responsive, but that causes the parent div `data` and `dataispod` to resize when I want it to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make use of [`background-image` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) or [`object-fit` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) with the value of `contain` to ensure it always fit inside your container. Example below:

(The example includes `filter` property to allow setting `border-radius` in the `contain`-ed image)

```css
/* Wrapper is optional, it is just to illustrate the container size */
.wrap {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/1000/400);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  filter: url('#filter-radius');
}

.img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  filter: url('#filter-radius');
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"><div class="bg"></div></div>
<hr />
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="img" src="https://placekitten.com/1000/400" />
</div>

<!-- Magic for border radius -->
<svg style="visibility: hidden" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter-radius">
      <!-- Create a blur of 4px radius from the original image -->
      <!-- (Transparent pixels are ignored, thus the blur radius starts at the corner of the image) -->
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />
      <!-- Filter out the pixels where alpha values that are too low, in this case the blurred corners are filtered out -->
      <feColorMatrix
        in="blur"
        mode="matrix"
        values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 100 -50"
        result="mask"
      />
      <!-- As the final result is now blurred, we need to use the mask we obtained from previous step to cut from the original source -->
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="mask" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ah this is just what I needed, I'll be making use of the background-image property from now on. Thank you so much, this really helped a lot!

Comment: Is there any way for me to keep the border-radius property with this code? I want it to be visually consistent with other elements of the website.

Comment: Hi @MihailoMitrović, it should work well even with `border-radius`. Added an example in the answer

Comment: I need the corners to be rounded, not the sides. Sorry for the hassle and thanks for the help.

Comment: @MihailoMitrović Do you mean the corner of the image? If so, you can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567069/image-rounded-corners-issue-with-object-fit-contain

Comment: Yes, the corners of the image that I/you set as the background. The question doesn't deal with it as a background. Does that mean I can't do it this way?

Comment: Hi @MihailoMitrović, I have added the SVG filter magic to make it works, I will also include it in the original question, please help to upvote the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76106794/8888888

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I'll study the code now to see how it works. Upvoted!