# zoom a banner in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to zoom my banner but I want to keep the image quality, do you think that it's possible?

The person must take more space...
Here is an example....
[image]

```css
.mybanner{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  
}
```

```html
    
<img class="mybanner" src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/13/60rt.jpg" alt="banner">
```

Comment: Despite what movies may show, zooming into an image does **not** allow you to retain the same level of quality. If you enlarge an image it **will** pixelate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scale image to fit a bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994493/scale-image-to-fit-a-bounding-box)

Comment: You're zooming in on a raster image. How are you expecting there to not be a loss of quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to maintain the pixel quality, then the comment on the question is correct.

I have a feeling you are really looking to maintain the aspect ratio of the image as it currently looks a bit squished. What is happening in this case is that you have given the `img` element fixed `height` and `width` that do not match the image's natural aspect ratio and it ends up squishing the content to make it fit the dimensions you are asking for.

Here I changed the `width` to `auto`, allowing the browser to calculate that value according to the image's natural ratio.

```css
.mybanner{
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  
}
```

```html
<img class="mybanner" src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/13/60rt.jpg" alt="banner">
```

If you actually want to "zoom" the image, maybe using the image as a `background-image` of a `<div>` is better, where you can control the exact dimensions of the div and the image separately:

```css
.mybanner{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://zupimages.net/up/19/13/60rt.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300% auto;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybanner" role="img"></div>
```